# Attribute Error in Python. How to use match and group?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get the following to work. I've looked at the Python documentation, and I still don't know how to fix it. I'm getting an AttributeError, what am I doing wrong?

```
import re
text = '>:{abcd|}+)_(#)_@_Mitch_(@<$)_)*zersx!)Pamela@(_+)('
m = re.match(r'(?P<name1>[A-Z][A-Za-z]*) (?P<name2>[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)', text)
m.group('name1')
```

If the above is incorrect, how do I get it to output

```
>>> m.group('name1') = 'Mitch'
```

Comment: Note that `re.match` only matches the pattern against the start of the string. Use `re.search` to get a match anywhere. (Not that you will anyway, in this particular case.)

Comment: Your regex does not actually grab anything.

Comment: @taesu What do you mean? Could you please clarify? Thank you.

Comment: Your regex doesn't match the input string `text` so nothing can be captured. If you put a `.*` in the middle of your regex instead of the space between the two capture groups, it works as I imagine you intended

Comment: As @msw commented, the problem is in the middle. You have a space (" ") that matches literally, and the 2 names are supposed to be one after the other. I recommend you try your pattern online in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fC7gR9/1)

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting to check that the regex actually matched anything. If it doesn't then both the `.match()` and `.search()` functions will return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the named group you are trying to reference was not actually matched in that string for that pattern.

Try to call groups on the returned value and you will see a tuple of all matched groups.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Python-related issue: the unmatched groups are not initialized and thus fail the whole match. You need to **explicitly state an empty alternative inside the group** for it to be really optional and work as in other regex flavors. Also, you have `_`, not a space between, so I suggest using a `[\s_]` character class to match both alternatives:

So, in your case, you can do it like this:

```
(?P<name1>[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)[\s_](?P<name2>[A-Z][A-Za-z]*|)
                         ^^^^^                        ^^
```

See [a regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tM2mJ2/1)

Sample [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/pyRt1S):

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?P<name1>[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)[\s_](?P<name2>[A-Z][A-Za-z]*|)')
test_str = u">:{abcd|}+)_(#)_@_Mitch_(@<$)_)*zersx!)Pamela@(_+)("
match = re.search(p, test_str)
if match:
    print(match.group("name1")) # => Mitch
```